# Can the direction extension for Flot only draw one arrow on a line rather than one arrow on each endpoint?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Pretty much as simple as the title. In the direction plugin arrows can only be drawn if you have two arrows (one for each endpoint). I'd like to just draw one arrow on an end point. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a direct option for this but if you give the angle for any one point as `infinity` it seems to suppress the arrow on that point:

```
$.plot(
    "#placeholder",
    [
        [[1, 10, 1e1000], [2, 20,  1e1000], [3, 33,  1e1000], [4, 13,  1e1000], [5, 8,  1e1000], [6, 26, 45]]
    ],
    {
        series: {
             points: {
                show: true,
                radius: 3,
                fill: false,
                symbol: 'circle'
            },
             lines: {
                show: true,
                lineWidth: 2
            },
             direction: {
                show: true
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Produces:

[image]

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/34AJx/).